# Query two tables in one query - Parse

Tags: sql, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to return the objects from two queries? For example:

```
PFQuery *queryOne = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Happy"];

PFQuery *queryTwo = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Places"];
[query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"restaurant"];


PFQuery *join = // somehow join both queryOne and queryTwo

[join findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {
    // here result would contain objects from both queryOne and queryTwo
}];
```

So if queryOne would return user A, B, C and queryTwo would return places D, E, F then result would contain [A, B, C, D, E, F]

Is this possible? If not, what's the best way to get the result of two asynchronous requests? I basically want to display this data in a tableview but don't want to show anything until I have the merged results from both queries...

Comment: Is there a relationship between the objects you want to query from the two tables? As far as I know, there is no method to get data from two different classes in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't give you any Objective-C code, since I've only done this in Swift, but I did two nested queries, along with dispatch groups. In my case, the two different classes were related, but you could do it anyway.

In Swift, it could kind of look like this:

```
//Create Dispatch Group
let group = dispatch_group_create()
let query1 = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.whereKey("status", isEqualTo: "Happy")
dispatch_group_join(group)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
//Your block, might add model objects to array or similar
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    for object in objects {
        myArray.append(object)
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}

let query2 = PFQuery(className: "Places")
query.whereKey("type", isEqualTo: "restaurant")
dispatch_group_join(group)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    //Same thing as above, maybe another array or something, and in the end
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}

//This is a "listener" for when the groups are finished
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    println("All done")
                    //reload TableView when all data is Fetched
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

I've used this successfully with arrays of the data fetched. Sorry for the Swift, if you like this approach I could try to help you translate some of it to Obj-C. Grand Central Dispatch Groups is your Google term.